# gganimate in R with gaps in dates

Tags: r, date, gganimate

I would like to animate snow depth over time.

My original code:

```
data = read.csv('data/processed/01_SnowDepths.csv', header = T)

myplot=ggplot(data, aes(x=as.Date(Date,format="%m/%d/%Y"), y=Depth)) +
  geom_line(linewidth=1,col="Blue")+
  geom_point(size=4)+
  xlab("Date")+
  ylab("Snow Depth [ft]")+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 20),axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"))+
  #gganimate specific bits:
  transition_reveal(index)+
  #labs(title = "{frame_along}",size=20)+ 
  ease_aes('linear')

animated =animate(myplot,fps = 10, width = 750, height = 500, renderer = gifski_renderer())
```

Produces this GIF:

[image]

The problem is that I have a gap in data in April (the straight line) that I would like the animation to jump over. However, transition_reveal() seems to treat it as a continuous axis.

I have got around this by adding an index to my dataframe and using that as the transition:

```
data = read.csv('data/processed/01_SnowDepths.csv', header = T)
data$index <- 1:nrow(data)

myplot=ggplot(data, aes(x=as.Date(Date,format="%m/%d/%Y"), y=Depth)) +
  geom_line(linewidth=1,col="Blue")+
  geom_point(size=4)+
  xlab("Date")+
  ylab("Snow Depth [ft]")+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 20),axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"))+
  #gganimate specific bits:
  transition_reveal(index)+
  #labs(title = "{frame_along}",size=20)+ 
  ease_aes('linear')

animated =animate(myplot,fps = 10, width = 750, height = 500, renderer = gifski_renderer())
```

[image]

The problem is now I can't use the {frame_along} parameter for my title. Any ideas for how I can have the animation omit the missing dates and still be able to use the date for my title?

Comment: What do you mean by: "I would like the animation to jump over". The two animations are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data2, aes(x=dates, y=Depth)) +
  geom_line(linewidth=1,col="Blue")+
  geom_point(size=4)+
  xlab("Date")+
  ylab("Snow Depth [ft]")+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 20),axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"))+
  #gganimate specific bits:
  transition_reveal(dates)+
  labs(title = "{frame_along}",size=20)+ 
  ease_aes('linear')
```

[image]

data:

```
structure(list(dates = structure(c(19358, 19359, 19360, 19361, 
19362, 19363, 19364, 19365, 19366, 19367, 19368, 19369, 19370, 
19371, 19372, 19373, 19374, 19375, 19376, 19377, 19378, 19379, 
19380, 19381, 19382, 19383, 19384, 19385, 19386, 19387, 19388, 
19389, 19390, 19391, 19392, 19393, 19394, 19395, 19396, 19397, 
19398, 19399, 19400, 19401, 19402, 19403, 19404, 19405, 19406, 
19407, 19408, 19409, 19410, 19411, 19412, 19413, 19414, 19415, 
19416, 19417, 19418, 19419, 19420, 19421, 19422, 19423, 19424, 
19425, 19426, 19427, 19428, 19429, 19430, 19431, 19432, 19433, 
19434, 19435, 19436, 19437, 19438, 19439, 19440, 19441, 19442, 
19443, 19444, 19445, 19446, 19447, 19448, 19449, 19450, 19451, 
19452, 19453, 19454, 19455, 19456, 19457, 19458, 19459, 19460, 
19461, 19462, 19463, 19464, 19465, 19466, 19467, 19468, 19469, 
19470, 19471, 19472, 19473, 19474, 19475, 19476, 19477, 19478, 
19479, 19480, 19481, 19482, 19483, 19484, 19485, 19486, 19487, 
19488, 19489, 19490, 19491, 19492, 19493, 19494, 19495, 19496, 
19497, 19498, 19499, 19500, 19501, 19502, 19503, 19504, 19505, 
19506, 19507, 19508), class = "Date"), Depth = c(2.2, 1.6, 2.4, 
1.6, 1.6, 2.5, 2.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.8, 1.2, 2.5, 2.1, 1.4, 3, 2.2, 
2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.6, 2.3, 2.3, 1.6, 1.2, 1.9, 1.8, 1.8, 1.4, 1.7, 
1.9, 2.5, 1.6, 1.3, 1.2, 2.6, 2, 2.6, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 2.5, 2.5, 
3, 2.3, 1.6, 1.5, 2.6, 2.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.7, 2.1, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 
2.4, 1.2, 2.7, 2, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.9, 2.9, 1.6, 2.2, 1.5, 1.5, 
2.5, 1.7, 1.4, 1.2, 2.9, 2.2, 1.3, 2.2, 2.1, 2.7, 2.4, 2.2, 2.5, 
2.5, 1.8, 1.6, 2.1, 1.6, 2.7, 1.9, 1.2, 2.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.5, 2.1, 2.5, 1.9, 1.3, 
2.3, 1.1, 1.5, 2.4, 2.7, 2.6, 1.4, 1.8, 2.6, 2.4, 2.2, 1.3, 2.2, 
2, 2.6, 1.1, 1.5, 2.8, 1.3, 2.9, 1.8, 2.7, 2.8, 2, 2.5, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-151L))
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I am looking for because the frames still cycle through the dates where there is no data. I would like it to skip over the period with no data...